# Coordinate flip for SVG clip path?

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have a div that is being clipped using `<clipPath>`element from inside an SVG. Everything is fine except I need the clipped portion of the red div to be anchored to the bottom left corner instead of the top left corner. Like so:

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojxuq.png)

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhRzU.png)

When browser window is resized, the clipped red div should stick to the bottom left corner like it is currently doing with the top left corner. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/gZvzjb). Is there anyway to do this? Do I need to flip the coordinate plane somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Coordinate flip" might not be a good name for what you try, since that would imply your clip path shape would be inverted - from your examples it seems you only want to translate it.

The way to do this may seem a bit convoluted, but it works: position the `<svg>` element just where your clipped div is, with the same size. Then you can take advantge of SVG positioning mechanisms to move the path in relation to its dimensions: First, move it up (negative y direction) such that its lower border sits at the top, by the amount of its height. Then, move it down again (positive y direction) by 100% of the `<svg>` height.

The next problem is that you have to combine absolute and relative translation. In CSS, you could write that as `calc(100% - 33px)`, but that doesn't work here. Instead you first move the path up with an attribute `transform="translate(0,-33)"`, and then you reference it with a `<use>` element, which has the advantage that it has a `y` attribute for positioning that can take percentage values.

```css
#Song2{
  top: 3.3333vh;
  right: 1.6%;    
  position: absolute;
  width: 47.6%;
  height: 16.6666vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
} 

#Song2svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#Song2sub{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: url(#fltcnrCP1);
}
```

```html
<div id="Song2">
  <svg id="Song2svg">
    <defs>
      <path id="cpsource" transform="translate(0,-33)" d="M0 0v18.608c0 1.032.476 2.007 1.29 2.643l14.22 11.111c.59.461 1.317.711 2.066.71h159.695V0z"/>
      <clipPath id="fltcnrCP1">
        <use href="#cpsource" y="100%" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <div id="Song2sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! It works great! Would have never thought of that. Where did the 33px value come from? Did you just eyeball it?

Comment: The 33 must be the viewbox height. Figured it out. Thanks again. Big help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just rotate the red element and move it?

Comment: I guess that would work. But I need it to be responsive. So how ever the browser window is resized, I need the red element to sit perfectly in the bottom left corner. How might I do that? A transform maybe?